# Will there be an ARP-Request to a gateway outside the subnet?

Tags: arp, gateway

This is a question from an exam I don't know the answer to. A client has a wrong configuration: He thinks his only gateway is not in his own subnet and needs the MAC address of the gateway. Will he even try to reach the gateway with an ARP-Request?

Comment: ARP is only used for the local subnet (if it is MAC based). MAC addresses outside your local network are irrelevant.

Comment: Does this mean the client will not send the request? So with this wrong configuration the client will not even try to communicate with clients outside his network if his ARP table is empty? (The linked "duplicate" answer doesn't answer my question.)

Comment: That I was trying to say: IP addresses outside a node's subnet are never ARPed, whether gateway or anything else.